# ASP application on IIS

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I have an IIS server and a .NET 4.5.2 application.
When the application is uploaded to the server, including the web.config generated by Visual Studio 2017, the "default document" functionality of the site more generally is broken.

For instance:

https://example.com/php-project/?queryinfo does not work, it loads a 404.
https://example.com/php-project/index.php?querinfo DOES work.

I've tried adding manual entries to web.config under system.webserver section. No joy.

The default document list, viewed via IIS GUI, is displaying all the default document entries included with IIS by default as well as my index.php entry properly. It's like something about files generated by Visual Studio 2017 is overriding the IIS settings.

Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The order of the items in Default Document matter, so make sure you have `index.php` at the right place. You can reorder the list and try again.

Comment: index.php is at the top. None of the default documents work. Browsing to any bare folder URL lists a 404.

Comment: Further clues, if I move the "staticfile" handler mapping above any of the extensionless URL handlers, PHP default documents start working. but then the main web app breaks and won't load.

Comment: That indicates the culprit is ASP.NET routing, which takes higher priority than IIS routing. You might tune the routing rules to make it work with your PHP pages, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs But if possible, host them as two sites and set up a reverse proxy to control the overall routing.